cesium tile 'hanging' on deckgl
I am trying to render cesium point tiles with deckgl, with mapbox basemap.
index.js
import { load } from '@loaders.gl/core';
import {Tileset3D} from '@loaders.gl/tiles';
import { CesiumIonLoader } from '@loaders.gl/3d-tiles';
import { WebMercatorViewport } from '@deck.gl/core';
import { Deck } from '@deck.gl/core';
import { Tile3DLayer } from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';
import {ScatterplotLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'; // Ensure mapbox-gl is imported
import {MapboxOverlay} from '@deck.gl/mapbox';


// Create a Deck.gl TileLayer to display the tileset
const tileLayer = new Tile3DLayer({
  id: 'tile-3d-layer',
  data: '....',
  loader: CesiumIonLoader,
  loadOptions: {
    'cesium-ion': {accessToken: '....'}
  },
  pointSize: 0.5
});

// Create the Mapbox GL JS map
const MAP_STYLE = 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-nolabels-gl-style/style.json';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'app',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
  accessToken: MAPBOX_TOKEN,
  center: [73.851210,
    18.516729],
  zoom: 11
});

map.once('load', () => {
  const deckOverlay = new MapboxOverlay({
    interleaved: true,
    layers: [
      tileLayer
    ]
  });

  map.addControl(deckOverlay);
});

With this set-up, I see that point cloud is sort of hanging rather than based on ground:

It seems its an issue related to projections/coordinate systems. I understand that cesium data is in EPSG:4978.
There is some deckgl documentation on coordinate systems, but I am not sure what code changes would make it compatible with deckgl.
Any lead would help?
